# Hazelcast Deserialization: Parent class attributes values are null after deserializatioin

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have two class Parent Class and Child classes as below:

```
 @MappedSuperclass
 public  class ParentEntity implements  DataSerializable {
        private String createdBy;
        private Date createdAt;

        public String getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }
        public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }
        public Long getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt.getTime();
        }
        public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
        }
       @Override
       public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(createdBy);
        out.writeLong(this.getCreatedAt());
       }
      @Override
      public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        createdBy = in.readUTF();
        createdAt = new Date(in.readLong());
      }
 }
```

Child class is as below:-

```
public class Child_Entity  extends ParentEntity implements DataSerializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
   }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(id);
        out.writeUTF(name);
    }
    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        id = in.readUTF();
        name = in.readUTF();
      }
  }
```

I fetch these value from database and put into hazelcast cache iMap.
While getting values from cache I am getting id and name value correct, but createdAt and createdBy (Parent Class attributes ) values are null.
How can it is possible to serialize parent class also with child class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call super-class serialization methods in the child class methods. For instance;

```
public class Child_Entity  extends ParentEntity implements DataSerializable {
private String id;
private String name;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id; }
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    super.writeData(out);
    out.writeUTF(id);
    out.writeUTF(name);
}
@Override
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    super.readData(in);
    id = in.readUTF();
    name = in.readUTF();
  }}
```

Comment: Now its giving following exception:-    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -22
 at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
 at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readUTF(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:569) ~[hazelcast-3.10.4.jar:3.10.4]

Comment: Can you please share the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks,solution working, exception was occured due to currepted data.